# Multiple subplots of a dataframe into a single jpg - Python

Tags: python, dataframe, plot

I have a dataframe as the following:

```
    state           year    SUR index
0   Aguascalientes  1997    1.116118
1   Aguascalientes  1998    1.129570
2   Aguascalientes  1999    1.129570
3   Aguascalientes  2000    1.129570
4   Aguascalientes  2001    1.340662
```

with 32 different states. I need to plot how has the sur index has evolved over the years and therefore I need 32 different graphs in a single jpg with 4 grafs per row and a total of 8 rows.

What I tried:

```
def plotting(df):
    pp = PdfPages('multipage.pdf')
    for estado in df['state'].unique():
        plt.plot(df['year'].unique(),df['SUR index'][df['state']==estado],"b")
        plt.ylabel('Sur index')
        plt.xlabel('Año')
        plt.title(estado)
        plt.savefig(pp, format='pdf')
        plt.figure()
    pp.close()
```

However, the first states gets all the data from other states and I have 32 different lines in that one. Also, I haven't found a way to have it in the 8*4 way I need it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code, for your example you will need to adjust the size of the axes grid (to 8x4).

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['State'] = (['a','b','c','d']*30)
df.sort_values(by='State', inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
df['year'] = range(1990, 2020)*4

df['SUR'] = np.random.uniform(0,100,120)


fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2)
for (name, df), ax in zip(df.groupby('State'), axes.flat):
    df.plot(x='year',y='SUR', ax=ax, legend=False)
    ax.set_title(name)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

To add labels to the axes you need to call:

```
ax.set_xlabel(...)
ax.set_ylabel(...)
```

To save the figure call:

```
fig.savefig(...)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank´s for your help. I get 2 errors though, the first one is: matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure. Which I get when I use plt.show(). Furthermore, When I save it I only get the last one of the states.The grid does show me 32 plots, but the only one with values is the last state.

Comment: Are you using jupyter? How are you running the code?

Comment: Yes, jupyter notebook, I wrote it exactly as you said (python 3.6)

Comment: At the start of the notebook put: %matplotlib notebook. Let me know if that doesn't work. Also you don't need a plt.show()